# Android Studio - Class File Status Unkown

Tags: android, android-studio

Just a small thing.
One class is showing up with a browny-red:

[image: browny-red]

colour. Hex: 993300.

Looking in `settings>Editor>Colors & Fonts>File Status` - I see that its defined as "Unknown".

Not sure what this means. Doesn't seem to be causing any issues.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The color difference is because you're using VCS (in my Android Studio, it's because of git). The browny-red color is a sign that the class is not yet added to the git. After you add it to the git (via `git add` command), the color will be changed to green.

Comment: ... or other VCS that has Android Studio integration